# How to do a basic sha256 encryption that matches the results on (website in description)

Tags: python-3.x, sha256

I'm setting up a login validation function to compare user entered password against the one stored in db. The db passwords are sha256 then a salt is added to the front and then sha256 again.

This is what I'm currently doing but it does some extra things apparently so I'm not getting just the basic sha256 for example like this website provides https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
passwordCandidate = "test"
passwordCandidate = sha256_crypt.encrypt(passwordCandidate)
print(passwordCandidate, file=sys.stderr)
```

What I want to get is:
`9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`

What I'm getting is:
`$5$rounds=535000$VZ4p1Kf9FmCL9Czc$.zvnilwPGcHhL54nq13LLrSxi0BXvSl0vW5C0zy5ya/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work with `hashlib`

```
import hashlib

passwordCandidate = "test"
print(hashlib.sha256(passwordCandidate.encode()).hexdigest())

# print : 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```